# Is it possible to run an Adobe Edge Animate Project with a single HTML File?

Tags: javascript, html, include, jquery-animate, adobe-edge

My HTML File looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
    <title>Unbenannt</title>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime-->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://animate.adobe.com/runtime/5.0.0/edge.5.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .edgeLoad-EDGE-720796712 { visibility:hidden; }
    </style>
<script>
   AdobeEdge.loadComposition('OrgAnimation', 'EDGE-720796712', {
    scaleToFit: "none",
    centerStage: "none",
    minW: "0",
    maxW: "undefined",
    width: "1250px",
    height: "800px"
}, {"dom":{}}, {"dom":{}});

</script>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime End-->

</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
    <div id="Stage" class="EDGE-720796712">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I have the JS-File called "OrgAnimation_edge.js" so I'm assuming it gets loaded at

> AdobeEdge.loadComposition('OrgAnimation'...

It works -

But now my Question: **Is it possible to put the js code from OrgAnimation_edge.js into the HTML file somehow and make it work with just that single file?** I couldn't figure it out :(

Comment: I'm thinking `AdobeEdge.loadComposition` comes from the `script` tag above it. `"...edge.5.0.0.min.js"`

Comment: yeah, I guess so - but I'm not sure how that can help me solve my question.
Thanks for pointing it out though, I'm not very familiar with this Animate Edge stuff yet and didn't realize it.

Comment: no problem, never seen it either. but what you're wanting to do, would most likely require inspecting the contents of those files, in order to load properly. And with a _minified_ version, *really* tough...

Comment: Ok, I found the source of the function `loadComposition` ...but I'm definitely not understanding it ;(...
Well that's an answer too I guess: "It's not easily possible, you would have to create some complicated additional code for that" :D

Comment: curious, why is that you want to include everything in one single HTML?

Comment: I'm trying to upload it to our Red-Dot CMS at work. But I'm not in the IT department so I don't have any access to templates and so on. All I can do is make a link to a file that I upload. :D